# Getting PHP array to JavaScript through Json

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays, json

Hey, I've got a PHP file that that echo's an array that has been encoded with json_encode. This file is used by the jQuery ajax function to retrieve the array. I am unable to figure out how to use the array though, I have managed to alert variables but not arrays. Here is my code:

```
function sessionStatus(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({type:"POST", url:scriptRoot+"sessionStatus.php", success:function(data){
                alert(data[0]);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
json_encode(array("data1","data2"));


$.getJSON("sessionStatus.php",function(data){
      alert(data[0]);
});
```

Should alert "data1"

Comment: Thnx, didnt know I could do that ;)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use

data.property as an object not like an array[property]